# C# error(using interface methods): An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, api, static

I'm having trouble using a third party API that has outdated documentation, so I'm trying to figure out why this piece of @#$! isn't working. And by @#$! i mean "code", of course :)

So as far as i know WAPISoap is a public interface that I have obtained by adding a web reference in visual studio.

I also know the Describe() method accepts two parameters, a string and an object of type credential and it returns a string. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Here's what i got so far:

```
using WAPIClient;
using System;
using Project1.WsWWDAPI;
namespace WAPIClient
{
    class ResellerAPI
    {
        public void CallDescribe()
        {
            String sReturnXml;
            Credential m_Crededential = new Project1.WsWWDAPI.Credential();
            m_Crededential.Account = "account";
            m_Crededential.Password = "password";
            String sCLTRID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            sReturnXml = WAPISoap.Describe(sCLTRID, m_Crededential);
            Console.WriteLine(sReturnXml);
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ResellerAPI reseller = new ResellerAPI();
            reseller.CallDescribe();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What line is the error on? The line with `Describe()`?

Comment: yeah, the error is when i try to call the method WAPISoap.Describe(sCLTRID, m_Crededential);

Answer (score 1):

The `Describe` method is not static, which means you need to call it on an instance of the `WAPI` class:

```
WsWWDAPI.WAPI m_WAPIObj = null;
WsWWDAPI.Credential m_Crededential = null;

public void Init()
{
    m_WAPIObj = new WsWWDAPI.WAPI();
    m_Crededential = new WsWWDAPI.Credential();
    m_Crededential.Account  = "account";
    m_Crededential.Password = "password";
}
public void CallDescribe()
{
    String sReturnXml;
    String sCLTRID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    sReturnXml = m_WAPIObj.Describe(sCLTRID, m_Crededential);
    Console.WriteLine( sReturnXml );
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ResellerAPI reseller = new ResellerAPI();
    reseller.Init();
    reseller.CallDescribe();
}
```

See: http://products.secureserver.net/guides/wsapiquickstart.pdf

Comment: thats what the documentation says, however the WAPI class does not exist

Comment: @ezra: Are you using an old reference?

Comment: i'm using the one in that document, specifically https://api.ote.wildwestdomains.com/wswwdapi/wapi.asmx?wsdl

Comment: yeah, its still not working, I can't find WAPI in the object browser either

Comment: Try replacing `WsWWDAPI.WAPI` with `WsWWDAPI.WAPISoap`.

Comment: see, but that wouldn't work either because WAPISoap is an interface. I can try with WAPISoapClient (which is a separate class)

Comment: @ezra: I'm supplying guesses right now. I've never used this API before.

Comment: its ok I think I got it to work, but thanks for all your help

Comment: @ezra: If you still have problems, try contacting support.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you use non-static method in static context - you should have instance of the WAPISoap in order to call member function which is not static

Comment: You're right - I guess it's some browser behvior, I've navigated out of my edit :-(

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to create an instance of WAPISoap and then call Describe on that instance.

Comment: I can't instantiate an interface as far as i know

Comment: No, you can't instantiate an interface, but then there must be a class that implements that interface that you can instantiate, or a static method somewhere that can return an instance of a class that implements the interface.

Comment: Thanks that helps, i'll try looking for the class